Renders with horizontal darker bar in cycles with GPU
I have an issue with several renders of a project.
As you can see in the attached snapshot, during a Cycles render appear several horizontal bars or lines with different coloration or darkened, and I don't know why... (it occurs with different cams in this interior project)
I've made these renders before in 50% resolution without facing this problem. But with 100% resolutions it appears (4500x3000 pixels).
It only happens with GPU. In CPU mode it works correctly (but it takes 3-4 times longer to do the render).
I've tested in CUDA instead of OptiX, and it solves the problem with one of my renders, but not with others, so this is not a permanent solution.
Blender 4.1.1
Mac & Windows (I've tested in both systems)
Please, could you help me with this problem?
Thanks and best regards,
Jose.


Sorry, this does not seem to be a problem with using Blender, it is rather a hardware problem or a bug. I would recommend you try updating your GPU drivers and/or report it as a bug. In any case I think it is off-topic on this site. Or we would need your file to check if our hardware has the same problem rendering it.

It's not a hardware problem because I've the same problem in a Macbook Pro M1 Max, with different GPU. How can I send you the file?

You can upload files at https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit them into your question.
